# Developer portal device list goes empty

Tags: ios, device

I'm 200% sure that there were about 70 devices registered on the company's developer portal, now it's empty.

I've been working here a year now, and I managed the "renewal" of the certificates and such when the apple-year was over. Everything was fine, I was even offered a chance to remove devices at the time, which I did for about 5 of them.

This will sound silly, but I clearly remember having 69 active devices and that was about 3 months ago, last time I checked.

Now it's empty.

Infomration :

- It's an Entreprise account
- We sold one of our apps and added an admin to the developer portal so he could access certificates/profiles for the sold app (which was on enterprise distribution). The sale was about 6 months ago and the client registered devices are gone. I assume they've added it to their own account while managing the transfer.

My questions :

Do the devices have an expiration date ?
Can someone remove devices without us being notified (even though there is no reason for them to do so)
Does adding a device to an account removes it from other accounts?
Any relevant information to share?

Comment: Devices don't have expiration, as you mentioned you renew them when year ends. There is only disable feature not delete the device and you can have one device in several accounts as well. But this question is off-topic here, it would be better to report to Apple that issue if you sure for 100% that this is not your failure

Comment: Well I didn't know where to ask, and I don't wanna file a support ticket if someone can just tell me if I did something silly first. I was really hoping that they do expire.
Do you think I can ask for activity logs on my account?

Comment: Maybe [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)? I don't think you will get an activity log, but you can try to ask restore your devices list, this is more like to be possible

Comment: Alright. Sorry about the apple.stackexchange, I had actually no idea it even existed.

Thanks for your time & support man :)